# Why PSQL meta command cannot be execute at mutliline

Tags: postgresql, psql

Just found out `\COPY` command can only be execute at one single line, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143816/any-way-to-list-all-user-defined-postgresql-functions) answer's query multiple times.
This way seems very unfriendly for writing long queries. And not easy to find out why.
I don't think that's a bug, then why.

Comment: Why? Because it has been implemented that way. [It is documented though](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) "*Parsing for arguments stops at the end of the line, or when another unquoted backslash is found. ... But in any case, the arguments of a meta-command cannot continue beyond the end of the line.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and if you are copying out to a file:

> Another way to obtain the same result as \copy ... to is to use the SQL COPY ... TO STDOUT command and terminate it with \g filename or \g |program. Unlike \copy, this method allows the command to span multiple lines; also, variable interpolation and backquote expansion can be used.

For copying in from a file, borrowing from what `pg_dump` does:

```
CREATE TABLE csv_test (col1 integer, col2 integer);

cat csv_test.csv 

COPY 
  csv_test 
FROM 
 stdin WITH CSV;
"19","9"
"19","5"
"19","5"
"19","15"
"19","5"

\i ~/csv_test.csv 
COPY 5

select * from csv_test ;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
   19 |    9
   19 |    5
   19 |    5
   19 |   15
   19 |    5
```